# Open "about:xxx" via bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I just played around with bookmarklets for a little while now, so I hope this question isn't too dumb.

My goal is to open `about:profiles` (Firefox V93.0) via a bookmark **in a new tab**. Opening a regular URL via a bookmarklet in a new tab/window is fairly straight forward using the `window.open`[-function](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-window-open-method):

`javascript:(function(){ window.open("https://somewebsite");})();`

Unfortunately this does not work for the `about:`-URI scheme, I tried to research how to get around this problem, but so far I had no luck. Any help, hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** What I also found out is that the otherwise working website-bookmarklet `javascript:(function(){ window.open("https://somewebsite");})();` won't work when I use it's bookmark while the tab I'm on displays any `config:`-page. Currently I'm thinking since URLs are a subset of URIs the `config:`-pages might not work with the `window.open`-function, but so far this is just a guess.

Comment: I don't think that possible, probably for security reasons.

Comment: Can't you just add it as a regular bookmark????

Comment: @Terry thanks, petty, I'll try to find a different way. Do you know if it would it be possible to do it via a addon? (I haven't searched yet myself).

Comment: @phuzi yes, I can and I have as a work around, but it is not my final goal.